# Two issues regarding line numbers

Tags: color, line-numbering

Here are my codes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,lineno}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
In the mathematical discipline of graph theory the Tutte-
Berge formula is a characterization of the size of a maximum matching in a 
graph. It is a generalization of Tutte theorem on perfect matchings, and is 
named after W. T. Tutte (who proved Tutte's theorem) and Claude Berge (who 
proved its generalization).

{\color{red}
\begin{theorem}
The size of a maximum matching of a graph $G=(V, E)$ equals
$$
\frac{1}{2} \min _{U \subseteq V}(|U|-\operatorname{odd}(G-U)+|V|),
$$
where odd $(H)$ counts how many of the connected components of the graph $H$ 
have an odd number of vertices.
\end{theorem}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My first question :

- why is there a significant gap in line numbers between 5 and 6 without any markings line numbers?

My second question:

- why are line numbers 5 and 6 also marked in red? I would like them to remain black.

Although I can adjust the position of   `{\color{red}}`, but **Theorem 1** in red becomes black. I wish it was red.

```
\begin{theorem}   
{\color{red} The size of a maximum matching of a graph $G=(V, E)$ equals
$$
\frac{1}{2} \min _{U \subseteq V}(|U|-\operatorname{odd}(G-U)+|V|),
$$
where odd $(H)$ counts how many of the connected components of the graph $H$ 
have an odd number of vertices.}
\end{theorem}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `$$...$$` is not supported in LaTeX documents and `lineno` can do nothing about this.

The manual suggests wrapping the display with `linenomath*`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\color{red!80!green}}
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\normalfont\tiny\sffamily\color{black}}

\linenumbers

\begin{document}

In the mathematical discipline of graph theory the Tutte-
Berge formula is a characterization of the size of a maximum matching in a 
graph. It is a generalization of Tutte theorem on perfect matchings, and is 
named after W. T. Tutte (who proved Tutte's theorem) and Claude Berge (who 
proved its generalization).

\begin{theorem}
The size of a maximum matching of a graph $G=(V, E)$ equals
\begin{linenomath*}
\[
\frac{1}{2} \min _{U \subseteq V}(|U|-\operatorname{odd}(G-U)+|V|),
\]
\end{linenomath*}
where $\operatorname{odd}(H)$ counts how many of the connected components of the graph $H$ 
have an odd number of vertices.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will typeset *all* theorems in red. Maybe you want to define a `redtheorem` environment, if only some of your theorems should be in red

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}% normal theorems
\newtheorem{redtheorem}[theorem]{Theorem}% red theorems
\AtBeginEnvironment{redtheorem}{\color{red!80!green}}
```

Note also that `\operatorname{odd}` must *always* be used and `odd $(H)$` would give a very disputable output.

Comment: Nice, do you have a solution for the color? I'd like to make both Theorem and their contents appear in red, but I don't want the line numbers to be affected.

Comment: @licheng you can ensure the line numbers always have a black font color by adding the line `\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\normalfont\tiny\sffamily\color{black}}` to your preamble.

Comment: @licheng I added support for color.

Comment: We may need to add `\usepackage{etoolbox}`

Comment: @licheng Only if you have an outdated version of LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you. I will update it.